# Does Salesforce communities support OAuth 2.0 SAML bearer assertion flow

Tags: community, oauth2, authentication, saml

I need to know if SF Communities supports OAuth 2.0 SAML bearer assertion flow. 
Based on what I read [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_auth_configure_oauth.htm&language=en_US) communities doesn't support SAML Assertion flow that is different from the SAML Bearer Assertion Flow. Is it right?

Have anyone ever used Oauth 2.0 SAML bearer assertion flow in order to authenticate external user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the summer 16 release it does.

Setup a connceted app
Use the clientID that is generated in the app as the Issuer in the SAML assertion
set the Recipient: $PORTAL URL$/services/oauth2/token 
set the Audience: $PORTAL URL$ 
Endpoint URL to send base64 encoded SAML assertion: $PORTAL URL$/services/oauth2/token